# Calculating monthly churn

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to calculate a monthly churn rate (for a given month: `number_of_people_who_unsubscribed / number_of_subscribers_at_beginning_of_month`).

I have a `subscribers` table that looks like this:

| id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-03-17 | null |
| 2 | 2020-06-21 | 2020-09-03 |

I can calculate churn for a *single month* with a query like this:

```
select
(
  /* Subscriptions that ended during January */
  select count(*)::decimal from subscriptions
  where end_date is not null
  and end_date >= '2021-01-01'
  and end_date <= '2021-01-31'
) /
(
  /* Subscriptions that were active at the beginning of January */
  select count(*)::decimal from subscriptions
  where end_date is null
  or end_date >= '2021-01-01'
) as churn
```

That gives me a single percentage of users who unsubscribed during January. However, I'd like to output this percentage for every month, so I can display it as a line chart. I'm not sure where to start - it feels like I need to loop and run the query for each month but that feels wrong. How could I make the same calculation, but without specifying the month manually? We can assume that there is at least one start_date and one end_date per month, so some kind of `group by` might work.

Ultimately I'm looking for an output that looks something like:

| month | churn |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-03 | 0.076 |
| 2020-04 | 0.081 |
| 2020-05 | 0.062 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your data logic and a sequence of months:

```sql
select to_char(running_month, 'yyyy-mm') as "month",
(
  /* Subscriptions that ended during January */
  select count(*)::numeric from subscriptions
  where end_date is not null
  and end_date >= running_month
  and end_date <= running_month + interval '1 month - 1 day'
) /
(
  /* Subscriptions that were active at the beginning of January */
  select count(*)::numeric from listings
  where end_date is null
  or end_date >= running_month
) as churn
from generate_series ('2020-01-01'::date, '2020-12-01'::date, interval '1 month') as running_month;
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked and is easy to understand. Thanks!